# Toggle on Yes/No buttons to continue on in survey

Tags: javascript, onclick, toggle

I want to know how to make sure either the Yes or No button is toggled in my survey in order to continue (so if either Yes or No has been clicked, the nextQuestion function can continue. If Yes or No has not been clicked, I will give an alert to the user to please make a selection). I currently have the progress bar and question updating in the same function. I figured it would make sense to add this bit to it but I am getting confused.

```
    var index_question = 0;
    var question_number = 2;
    var progress_question = 1;
    var percentage = 0;

    function nextQuestion(){

            if (index_question < 4) && ($(".btn-success").button('toggle')) {
                <!-- Question # and Question Text --> 
                document.getElementById("questionArea").innerHTML = questionSet[index_question];
                index_question ++;
                document.getElementById("questionNum").innerHTML = [question_number];
                question_number ++;
                <!-- Progress Bar -->
                percentage = ((([progress_question])*(100))/(5));
                progress_question++;
                $(".progress-bar").width([percentage] + "%");

             } 
        <!-- Survey Completed -->
        else {

            $(".progress-bar").width("100%");
            alert("Thank you for completing the survey!")

            }
        }

            <td><button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="questionDecision">Yes</button></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="questionDecision">No</button></td>

    function questionDecision() {
        $(".btn btn-success").button('toggle');
        $(".btn btn-danger").button('toggle');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to have a variable in the Javascript like `var answered_question = False;`, which is set to `True` in your `questionDecision` function after they have made a choice. Before advancing the user to the next question or updating the progress bar, always check `if(clicked_yes_or_no==True){ }`.

Comment: I tried to put something together fast but it's not working.  `var answered_question = False;  function yesDecision() {  answered question = True;  }  function nextQuestion() {  if (answered_question = True) {  if (index_question < 4) {` ...